# SimpleExoPlayer configuration issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer

I'm working on a project on Android Studio where i need an audio player. I chose Exoplayer. I included this dependency in my gradle file

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
```

Then I imported

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer
```

In my class, I'm creating a SimpleExoplayer instance as in the Hello World example

```kotlin
private val player: SimpleExoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
```

Then I do not have access to all the player methods specified in the javadoc. I can call prepare, isPlaying(), previous etc ... But no trace of addMediaItem or setMediaItem. It's probably something stupid, but i'm stuck on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods like `addMediaItem()`, `setMediaItem()`, were added in [v2.12.0](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md#2120-2020-09-11). Update your dependency version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.12.0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Android studio usually tells me when a dependency is outdated so I didn't think it was that ... No this time.